# Linux PAM: SSH key + 2FA (google authenticator) + password - Specify auth requirements per user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, pam, google-authenticator

I have installed and configured PAM on my Ubuntu server which is working correctly. To log in I want to require an SSH Key to be installed, a password to be provided and a valid code from an authenticator app.

The issue that I have is that I would like to add exceptions to these requirements on a per-user basis.

For example, I want to enforce all of these auth methods for my user account, but specify another user (git - for my GitLab installation) to be accessed by SSH key only (no password or 2FA code required) so the push and pull behaviour works.

The only way I have found to get round this at the moment is to set `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok` in the /etc/pam.d/sshd file, so the 2FA part is optional, as well as commenting out the `@include common-auth` line. This however means that while the 2FA part works, I am no longer asked for my password on my main account.

I have tried to do the following:

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user in git
@include common-auth
```

but this doesnt seem to work.

What do I need to do to enable all of the above auth methods by default, but add exceptions for specific user accounts like `git` etc?

Answer (score 4):

Let's break down these requirements a bit.

**Configuring SSH**

First, in order to require public keys *and* password to provide, you need to modify your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by adding this line:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

This way, everyone must have a public key, and must be able to provide their password upon login.

To make exceptions, use the `Match` block. For example, let's assume that users who aren't restricted are in the `come-as-please` group. Then add these line to the end of the `sshd_config` file:

```
Match Group come-as-please
    AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
```

Note the absence of the comma, which means that members of the group may use either public key, *or* keyboard-interactive (password) authentication.

**Configuring google-authenticator**

To use google authenticator module, you meed to modify the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file. After the

```
@include common-auth
```

line, add this one:

```
auth    required        pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Also, in order to enable two-factor authentication, you need to modify your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, adding this line:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

After this, restart the SSH daemon.

**Setting user access**

After the above modifications, you have the following access settings:

- Every user *must* have a public key installed, and *must* supply a password.
- If there is a `.google_authenticator` file in the user's home directory, then they *must* supply the corresponding authenticator code as well.
- Anyone who is member of the `come-as-please` group:

  - If they have a public key installed, they do *not* need to supply a password or the authenticator code, whether they have the `.google_authenticator` file in their home or not,
  - If they don't have a public key installed, they need to specify a password. They need to supply the authenticator code if the `.google_authenticator` file exists in their home directory.

Comment: Don't forget to add `auth required pam_permit.so` to the end of the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` when using `nullok` option 

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam#nullok